# Library plugin for WordPress

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I want to migrate a group's site from Joomla to WordPress. The group has a library for members and lends books for certain periods of time, etc. (Regular library functionality).

Although the site doesn't have a library functionality in it now, it would be something cool to add. And there's probably some plugin to add this to a page or something for WordPress.

Are you aware of something like this?

**EDIT**: The functionality would be:

- Tracking who borrowed or reserved a book for certain date.
- Which books are in stock,
  etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how this library functionality works?  Does it track who has which book and which books are available?  Does it allow peer-to-peer requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just come across this which looks like it might be what you're looking for

Web Librarian by Deepsoft.

http://www.deepsoft.com/home/products/web-librarian/

appears to be free, and released under a GNU license etc

Answer (score 1):

I have no such plugin directly at hand, I think it's worth to start a search for that on google and the wordpress.org plugin repository.

I could find some library / book related plugins so far, but nothing is about the workflow of lending books from a shared shelf:

- [OpenBook Book Data (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openbook-book-data/) - Displays a book's cover image, title, author, links, and other book data from Open Library.
- [Internet Book Database Book Widgets (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/internet-book-database-widgets/) - The Internet Book Database Bookshelf and Book Information from ISBN Widgets.
- [Amazon Book Picture from ASIN (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amazon-book-picture-from-asin/) - Allows to include images of books by asin or isbn from amazon through a simple tag.
- [Track The Book (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/track-the-book/) - Creates a dynamic KML file of book numbers and locations that were entered by visitors.
- [Current Book (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/current-book/) - Want to show your readers what book you're reading? That's just what this plugin does coincidentally.
- [Now Reading Reloaded (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/now-reading-reloaded/) - Allows you to display the books you're reading, have read recently and plan to read, with cover art fetched automatically from Amazon.

Comment: I know this one is old, but can any of these plugin be used for a rental business in general? I am planning to rent out 500 products so I need to have some kind of management tool and not my plain excell file ;)